# Regex to match the pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to match the regex that matches the sentence with following pattern:
1st part is occurrence of word/s.(eg: passed, died)
2nd part is the date in that sentence.
3rd part is, this should match only before the delimiter/dot/full stop.

Example:
Worth Scattergood (Dee) Lea passed on Thursday, `July 28, 2022`, Worth Scattergood (Dee) Lea passed away unexpectedly at age 88 with her three daughters at her side. Dee was born on April 26, 1934, in Radnor, Pennsylvania.

Here i need result of: `July 28, 2022`

But this should not match or find any result in following sentence:
Worth Scattergood (Dee) Lea passed on Thursday. Dee was born on April 26, 1934, in Radnor, Pennsylvania.

I tried with following expression but it is wrong as it match upto second sentence:

```
(passed|died)(.*?)(\w+)\d{1,2},?\s?\d{4}
```

Comment: Your pattern doesn't have a space between the month and day.

Comment: Try `\b(?:passed|died)\b[^.?!]*?\b(\w+\s*\d{1,2},\s?\d{4})(?!\d)`

Comment: @Barmar Even if it is there, there is a match with `Worth Scattergood (Dee) Lea passed on Thursday. Dee was born on April 26, 1934, in Radnor, Pennsylvania.`, so I guess the pattern posted is not the one OP used.

Answer (score 4):

You can match keywords `passed` or `died` and then allow upto 3 space separated substrings before matching date:

```bash
\b(?>passed|died)(?>\h+\S+){0,3}\h+\K\w+\h+\d{1,2},\h*\d{4}\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tXbVO0/1)

**Explanation:**

- `?>...)`: is atomic group
- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(?>passed|died)`: Match `passed` or `died`
- `(?>\h+\S+){0,3}`: Match 0 to 3 space separated substrings
- `\h+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `\K`: Resets matched info
- `\w+`: Match month name
- `\h+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `\d{1,2}`: Match date part 1 or 2 digits
- `,\h*`: Match comma followed by 0 or more whitespaces
- `\d{4}\b`: Match 4 digit year followed by word boundary

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```php
\b(?:passed|died)\b[^.?!]*?\b(\w+\s*\d{1,2},\s?\d{4})(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YNBW8q/1).

*Details*

- `\b(?:passed|died)\b` - a word boundary, a non-capturing group matching either `passed` or `died` (as whole words) and a word boundary
- `[^.?!]*?` - zero or more chars other than `.`, `!` and `?` as few as possible
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\w+\s*\d{1,2},\s?\d{4})` - Group 1: one or more word chars, zero or more whitespaces, one or two digits, comma, an optional whitespace, and four digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit immediately on the right is allowed.